# My method for finding a node in a double linked list isn't working properly and I don't know why?

Tags: java

Here's the code

```
public void findDNode(String name)
{
    DNode u = header;
    while(u != null)
    {

        if(name == u.getElement())
        {
            System.out.println(u.getElement());
            break;
        }
        else if (u == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: not found");
            break;
        }

        u = u.nextNode();
    }

}
```

For some reason when the node that I am looking for doesn't exist it's doesn't print the error: not found message.

edit: nevermind just realised when u== null the while loop won't happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u never becomes null inside the loop! Perform the check after the loop.

```
public void findDNode(String name)
{
    DNode u = header;
    while(u != null)
    {

        if(name == u.getElement())
        {
            System.out.println(u.getElement());
            break;
        }

        u = u.nextNode();
    }
   if (u==null)
       System.out.println("Error: not found");

}
```

Edit: and yes, you should use equals()

Answer (score 4):

You should use `equals()` to compare Java strings:

```
if (name.equals(u.getElement()))
{
  ...
```

Comparing strings using the `==` operator compares the references, which in most cases isn't the right thing to do.

Also, the "not found" logic is misplaced. It should probably be placed outside the loop (with an appropriate `if` condition).

Answer (score 0):

Other than using `equals()` instead of `==` to compare String there is another issue.

How can you have `if (u == null)` inside a `while(u != null)` loop. That `if (u == null)` block will never execute since while loop will end when `u == null`. That is the reason **Error: not found** is never printed.